# Full control user Getting error in recyclebinitemcollection: "Access Denied" in sharepoint 2010 client object model

Tags: client-object-model

List spRecycleCollection = new List();
                        Site collSite = _ctx.Site;

```
                    RecycleBinItemCollection collRBI = collSite.RecycleBin;
                    _ctx.Load(collRBI, items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(item => item.Author, item => item.DeletedBy, item => item.DeletedDate, item => item.ItemState, item => item.LeafName, item => item.Size, item => item.Title, item => item.DirName));

                    _ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 


                    int totolCount = collRBI.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < totolCount; i++)
                    {
                        SPRecycleItem spListItem = new SPRecycleItem();
                        try
                        {

                            List<MetadataDictionary> lstFieldsToDisplay = new List<MetadataDictionary>();
                            //For Getting Permission for List ITems
                            spListItem.Author = collRBI[i].Author.Title;
                            spListItem.DeletedBy = collRBI[i].DeletedBy.Title;
```

Comment: `_ctx` is properly initialized?

Comment: yes its proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added user to site collection administrators and its solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Site collSite = clientContext.Site;
RecycleBinItemCollection collRBI = collSite.RecycleBin;

clientContext.Load(collRBI);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Try the above code. Make sure the current user can see the Recycle Bin by opening it in the Browser.

Update

If you want additional properties, then you should include it in the `Load` method.

```
clientContext.Load(collRBI, items => items.Include(item => item.Author));

User u = collRBI[i].Author as User;
u.LoginName

OR

FieldUserValue u = collRBI[i].Author as FieldUserValue;
u.LookupValue
```

Comment: this is ok but with this solution i m getting error in below code: int totolCount = collRBI.Count;
                        for (int i = 0; i < totolCount; i++){ SPRecycleItem spListItem = new SPRecycleItem();
                            try
                            {

                                List<MetadataDictionary> lstFieldsToDisplay = new List<MetadataDictionary>();
                               List ITems
                                spListItem.Author = collRBI[i].Author.Title;
                                spListItem.DeletedBy = collRBI[i].DeletedBy.Title;

Comment: @user1111905 what is the error?

Comment: Getting this error on this line "spListItem.Author = collRBI[i].Author.Title;":The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: You should include those extra properties as you mentioned in your code. See my updated answer.

Comment: i've changed the code as you've suggested but giving the same error: _ctx.Load(collRBI);
                        _ctx.Load(collRBI, items => items.Include(item => item.Author));
                        _ctx.Load(collRBI, items => items.Include(item => item.DeletedBy));
                        _ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Take on step at a time. First try to get only the author and see it works before adding all other properties.

Comment: yes i've tried but i am getting error in author..

Comment: all other are working but in author and in deleted by i am getting error..

Comment: User fields are treated differently. Try my updated answer.

Comment: look at my whole code

Comment: what change should i do in that?i've updated code

Comment: Change `spListItem.Author = collRBI[i].Author.Title;` to `spListItem.Author = ((FieldUserValue)collRBI[i].Author).LookupValue;`

Comment: giving me syntax error : cannot convert type 'microsoft.sharepoint.client.user' to 'microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue'

Comment: Ok then use `spListItem.Author = ((User)collRBI[i].Author).LoginName;`

Comment: still not working :-( giving me error :The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Change include `items.Include(item => item.Author,item => item.Author.LoginName)`

Comment: than its giving error Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Comment: found any other sol?